# Objects within Objects (Name 'game' is not defined)

Tags: python, pygame

I code runs fine when I take the objects out of the inside of the Game object, but I want to define them inside of it. The program is supposed to take the string in the data object input it into a list within a list with one list, with the data in this list being the tile. But I just get this error message any idea?

```
import pygame        

class Map:
    grid = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    def __init__(self):
        self.loadMap("Test")
        self.printMap()
    def loadMap(self, mapno):
        for x in range(10):
            for y in range(10):
                #print(str(data.map_1[x][y])+", ("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
                #print(len(self.grid[0]))
                self.grid[x].append(Tile(game.data.map_1[x][y], x, y))
    def printMap(self):
        pass


class Tile:
    def __init__(self, tile, x, y):
        self.name, self.color = game.data.tile_type[str(tile)]
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x*50),(self.y*50),50,50)

class Data:
    tile_type = {
        "0":("Sea", (5, 28, 179)),
        "1":("Forest", (18, 122, 15)),
        "3":("River", (61, 181, 245)),
        "4":("Sand", (232, 232, 30)),
        "2":("Grass", (33, 235, 26)),
        "5":("House", (87, 61, 31))
    }

    map_1 = ((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
             (0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0),
             (0,4,4,4,2,2,5,4,0,0),
             (0,4,1,2,3,2,2,4,0,0),
             (0,4,1,5,3,2,1,4,0,0),
             (0,4,1,2,1,3,1,4,0,0),
             (0,4,4,4,4,3,1,4,0,0),
             (0,0,0,0,0,4,3,4,0,0),
             (0,0,0,0,0,4,1,4,0,0),
             (0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0))
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = Data()
        self.map = Map()
        pygame.init()
        size = 500
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((size,size))
        self.main()
    def main(self):
        while True:
            self.ev = pygame.event.poll()
            if self.ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                break
            surface.fill((255, 240, 53))
            pygame.time.delay(10)
game = Game()
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Tilesets.py", line 62, in <module>
    game = Game()
  File "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Tilesets.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.map = Map()
  File "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Tilesets.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.loadMap("Test")
  File "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Tilesets.py", line 13, in loadMap
    self.grid[x].append(Tile(game.data.map_1[x][y], x, y))
NameError: name 'game' is not defined
```

Comment: There just isn't anything defined as `game` in that method. It doesn't have anything to do with objects within objects or wheels within wheels. There just isn't a `game` there so python complains. You probably should pass the `game` instance as a parameter to your `Map` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the instance of `Game` within the `Map` instance, then you can pass `self` to `Map` when instantiating it, and assign it to the `Map` instance in its `__init__`:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        ...

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.map = Map(self)
        ...
```

Then, when you want to use it, you can simply use `self.game`:

```
self.grid[x].append(Tile(self.game.data.map_1[x][y], x, y))
```

And as abccd pointed out, you probably should be calling `main()` outside of `__init__`:

```
game = Game()
game.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies here:

```
game = Game()
```

The game never finish initializing because your program is still inside it's `def __init__` because you called `self.main()` inside it while there's a mainloop in `main`. so technically, it the game instance hasn't been fully defined yet. What you can change is do this instead. By calling the `main` function outside the `__init__`.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = Data()
        self.map = Map()
        pygame.init()
        size = 500
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((size,size))

    def main(self):
        while True:
            self.ev = pygame.event.poll()
            if self.ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                break
            surface.fill((255, 240, 53))
            pygame.time.delay(10)
game = Game()
game.main() # calling the main function here
```